# REST: Not able to add cookie

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, cxf

I am using Apache CXF framework for my REST based service.

In the HTTPServletResponse, I am adding a cookie (using addCookie(Cookie cookie) method) but it is not being added successfully because, whenever I call the same API again, I couldn't see/use the added cookie.

I am using a REST client to call the API and I could see Set-Cookie header in the Respose Headers, but it is not being set.

What would be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the cookie is set actually.You will notice that further requests to your api carry the cookie along with them in the "Request Headers". To check the cookie, include the following code snippet in your Service Implementation:

1. In the implementation class, add the following annotation

   ```
   @Context
   private HttpHeaders headers;
   ```
2. Now, in the method of that class where you want to check the headers, add this code

   ```
   if(headers.getRequestHeaders() != null) {
       for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.getRequestHeaders().entrySet()) {
           System.out.println("entry.getKey() >>>>>>>>>>> "+entry.getKey());
           System.out.println("entry.getValue() >>>>>>>>>> "+entry.getValue());
       }
   }
   ```

Here, entry.getKey() will show you the header name and entry.getValue() will be showing a list of string values that this key is holding. If set, your cookie will appear under the header "cookie". I hope that helps.
Thanks.